# how to capture change in records in pyspark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

Below is dataframe df1.

| EmpID | Work | StartTime | StopTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Call | 2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Call | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T15:00:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Break | 2023-06-02T15:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T15:15:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Call | 2023-06-02T15:15:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T17:00:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Break | 2023-06-02T17:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T17:15:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Call | 2023-06-02T17:15:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000 |

Below is dataframe df2.

| EmpID | Work | StartTime | StopTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000 |

Expected Output:

1 ) I have to find the records in df2 where the type of '**Work**' that is done in df2 for an EmpID on a date is not present in df1 for the Same EmpID and same Date.

Example: Planned OOF is present in df2 for Empid 1 on June 2nd but not in df1 for Empid 1 on June 2nd. I have to capture the two records of Planned OOF from df2 and add '00' as Type column to them.

2 ) I have to find common Work in df2 and df1 for Same EmpID on Same Day.

Example: '**Meal**' Work is present for Empid **1** on **June 2nd** in df2 and the Same work 'Meal' is present for Empid 1 on June 2nd in df1. I have to capture record from df1 an assgin 10 as Type and capture record from df2 and assign 11 as Type

| EmpID | Work | StartTime | StopTime | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 | 00 |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000 | 00 |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 10 |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 11 |

Extra:
Providing the dataframe query for df1 and df2

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("EmpID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Work", StringType(), True),
    StructField("StartTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("StopTime", StringType(), True)
])

data = [
    ("1", "Call", "2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Meal", "2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Call", "2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T15:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Break", "2023-06-02T15:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T15:15:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Call", "2023-06-02T15:15:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T17:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Break", "2023-06-02T17:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T17:15:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Call", "2023-06-02T17:15:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000")
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df1 = df1.withColumn("StartTime", to_timestamp("StartTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("StopTime", to_timestamp("StopTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))
```

Below is for df2:

```
data = [
    ("1", "Planned OOF", "2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Meal", "2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("1", "Planned OOF", "2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000", "2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000")
]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Convert StartTimeStamp and StopTimeStamp columns to timestamp data type
df2 = df2.withColumn("StartTime", to_timestamp("StartTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))
df2 = df2.withColumn("StopTime", to_timestamp("StopTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))
```

Comment: I have to find the records in df2 where the type of 'Work' that is done in df2 for an EmpID on a date is not present in df1 for the **Same EmpID and same Date**.--Can we ignore the time value from the date columns? from your sample input and output, I think it is enough to compare EmpId, work and just date. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step:1**

You can use the **left_anti** join to find the records in df2 where the type of 'Work' that is done in df2 for an `EmpID` on a date is not present in df1 for the Same `EmpID` and same Date. Then add '00' as `Type` column to that dataframe. Below is the code,

**Code:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, col, lit

# Find the records in df2 where the type of 'Work' that is done in df2 for an EmpID on a date is not present in df1 for the Same EmpID and same Date
df2_not_in_df1 = df2.join(df1, (df1.EmpID == df2.EmpID) & (date_format(df1.StartTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') == date_format(df2.StartTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) & (df1.Work == df2.Work), 'left_anti')

# Add '00' as Type column to the filtered records
df2_not_in_df1 = df2_not_in_df1.withColumn('Type', lit('00'))

# Select the required columns
df2_not_in_df1 = df2_not_in_df1.select('EmpID', 'Work', 'StartTime', 'StopTime','Type')

# Show the output
df2_not_in_df1.show()
```

| EmpID | Work | StartTime | StopTime | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T10:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 | 00 |
| 1 | Planned OOF | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T19:00:00.000+0000 | 00 |

**Step:2**

You can use the inner join to find common Work in df2 and df1 for Same `EmpID` on Same Day. Then capture record from df1 an assign 10 as `Type` and capture record from df2 and assign 11 as `Type`.

**Code**

```py
# Find common Work in df2 and df1 for Same EmpID on Same Day
# Rename the columns of df2
df2_renamed = df2.select([col(c).alias(c + '_df2') for c in df2.columns])

df_common = df2_renamed.join(df1, (df1.EmpID == df2_renamed.EmpID_df2) & (date_format(df1.StartTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') == date_format(df2_renamed.StartTime_df2, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) & (df1.Work == df2_renamed.Work_df2), 'inner').select(df2_renamed.columns)

# Add Type column to df1 records
df1_filtered = df1.join(df_common, (df1.EmpID == df_common.EmpID_df2) & (date_format(df1.StartTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') == date_format(df_common.StartTime_df2, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) & (df1.Work == df_common.Work_df2), 'inner')
df1_filtered = df1_filtered.withColumn('Type', lit('10'))

# Add Type column to df2 records
df2_filtered = df2.join(df_common, (df2.EmpID == df_common.EmpID_df2) & (date_format(df2.StartTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') == date_format(df_common.StartTime_df2, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) & (df2.Work == df_common.Work_df2), 'inner')
df2_filtered = df2_filtered.withColumn('Type', lit('11'))

# Combine the filtered dataframes
df_combined_filtered = df1_filtered.union(df2_filtered)

# Select the required columns
df_combined_filtered = df_combined_filtered.select('EmpID', 'Work', 'StartTime', 'StopTime', 'Type')

df_combined_filtered.show()
```

| EmpID | Work | StartTime | StopTime | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:10:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 10 |
| 1 | Meal | 2023-06-02T12:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T13:00:00.000+0000 | 11 |

**Step:3**

Union the outputs from step2 and step3.

```py
#Combine the df2_not_in_df1 dataframe with df_combined_filtered
df_combined = df_combined_filtered.union(df2_not_in_df1)

# Show the output
df_combined.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If there are two records for Meal Work  in df2 and two records for Meal in df1, then your Step-2 would give duplicate results. 
When you first join two df's to get df_common, you can select the records corresponding to to df2 and remove the duplicate records and again select the record corresponding to df1 and remove the duplicate records.